# Daily delete limit of posts?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

Does the daily limit of 5 self-deleted posts apply to recently made posts?

For example, if I mix up my meds, and make 6 colossally stupid posts in one day, will I be able to delete them in turn?

I hope this particular use case never comes to pass, but I think I've deleted more than 5 correct, but mediocre, unvoted posts in one day before, but I wanted to ask to see if that's true, or just my imagination.

Comment: There isn't a discriminator, that I know of. You're limited to 5 deletions per day of *any* of your posts. If it's really an emergency, flag for moderator attention and explain the situation. If the mod hasn't also mixed up *their* meds, they will oblige.

Comment: I support this because you're on meds

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recent posts are actually *more* important than old ones as far as the system is concerned. We're looking for ragequits, folks asking questions and deleting them the moment they get an answer, etc.

I agree there are probably scenarios where you should get a pass on this, but *hopefully* they are rare.

If you do bump into it, that's probably a good sign you should take a break and go for a walk or something.

Comment: `a good sign you should take a break and go for a walk or something` ftw :)